# How can an observer find out the before and after values of a observed property in ember.js 1.x?

Tags: ember.js

What I want to know is how to do this [How can an observer find out the before and after values of the observed property in Ember.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234781/how-can-an-observer-find-out-the-before-and-after-values-of-the-observed-propert)
with the last version of Ember.JS.

Now beforeObserver and observer send only 'this'(the object that is watching) and the the query. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2XumM/2/) and example.

```
fooWillChange: function() {
    console.log(
      arguments.length, //2
      arguments[0] == this, //true
      arguments[1] == 'foo' //true
    );
}.observesBefore('foo'),

fooDidChange: function() {
    //exactly equal fooWillChange
}.observes('foo')
```

in 'foo' case I can just pick the value with `get` but in the case of watching a property inside of an array(like `bar.@each.name`) this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

For observing array changes you can use the function addArrayObserver and then override the two functions willChange and didChange to read the changes.

I have created a jsbin as an [example](http://jsbin.com/ifenac/5/edit)

For more information visit [this](http://madhatted.com/2013/5/17/observing-enumerables-and-arrays-with-ember-js) link.

Comment: This works for watching changes of add/remove but not changes of properties in the elements of array(like `array.@each.name`)