# Know which item fires the event when observing @each

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm observing an Ember Data RecordArray like this:

```
myArray: function() {
  return MyRecord.find();
}.property(),

isDirtyChanged: function() {
  // Do something
}.observes('array.@each.isDirty');
```

I want to perform some operations on the particular record that fires the event. For example, if record 2 is modified:

MyRecord.find(2).set('my_property', 'some_value');

`isDirtyChanged` will get called and do some stuff with the record. How can I get a reference to the record that calls the observer, not just the array as a whole?

Comment: It's not quite what you're asking, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496446/how-can-an-observer-find-out-the-before-and-after-values-of-a-observed-property) has some info about using `addArrayObserver` which might help.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no way to tell. The docs don't mention how to do this either. See [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/) and [here](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_beforeObserver).

It does however mention this:

> Note, @each.property observer is called per each add or replace of an element and it's not called with a specific enumeration item.

Normally if you add a `obj` and `keyname` parameters to the observer function and call `obj.get(keyname)` you'll get the object you're watching. But since the keyname here is `array.@each.isDirty` that doesn't work.

```
isDirtyChanged: function(obj, keyname) {
  obj is the targen here the object wacthing the array
  keyname is 'array.@each.isDirty'
  // Do something
}.observes('array.@each.isDirty');
```

I'd love to be proven wrong though!

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bGN4/278/) try some stuff out.

Comment: `obj` in this case is the target, i.e. the observing object. I've read through the code and it seems impossible to get the particular object calling the observer.