# Ember.js: How do I determine if a property has really changed in an Observer?

Tags: ember.js

Let's say I have `Article`s which are backed by `Source`s. Each article has one source.

Sources have associated HTML which will be rendered on screen.

I want this HTML to be rendered **only** if the source changed.

```
App.ArticleView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.addObserver('controller.source.id', function() {
      console.log(arguments);
      renderHTML();
    });
  });
});
```

This behaves exactly as stated [in the addObserver documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_addObserver), "Note that the observers are triggered any time the value is set, regardless of whether it has actually changed. Your observer should be prepared to handle that."

If setting a `controller.model` of `Article` `A` with source `1` is followed by setting a `controller.model` of `Article` `B` with source `1`, the observer will call the method but **I want to prevent renderHTML() from happening**.

The documentation mentions "Observer Methods" which I'm not sure how to put to use in this case. Its signature (`function(sender, key, value, rev) { };`) looks exactly like what I need, but in my tests the `arguments` to the observer method are always `0: (current view), 1: "controller.source.id"`.

How can I get the previous value of `controller.source.id`, so as to determine whether to `renderHTML()` or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can an observer find out the before and after values of the observed property in Ember.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234781/how-can-an-observer-find-out-the-before-and-after-values-of-the-observed-propert)

Comment: That is more than 2 years old, and it doesn't work

Comment: heh good point, sorry about that. What if you store a copy of the property and check if it’s changed? If it has, you render and store a new copy of the property.

Answer (score 1):

`Ember.set` won't set the value if it's the same as the current value, so your observer won't fire unless the value changes.

Here's an example:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jiyesuzi/2/edit

And here's the code in `Ember.set` that does it (https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages_es6/ember-metal/lib/property_set.js#L73)

```
// only trigger a change if the value has changed
  if (value !== currentValue) {
    Ember.propertyWillChange(obj, keyName);
    if (MANDATORY_SETTER) {
      if ((currentValue === undefined && !(keyName in obj)) || !obj.propertyIsEnumerable(keyName)) {
        Ember.defineProperty(obj, keyName, null, value); // setup mandatory setter
      } else {
        meta.values[keyName] = value;
      }
    } else {
      obj[keyName] = value;
    }
    Ember.propertyDidChange(obj, keyName);
  }
```

Unfortunately for you're case, Ember considers changing a portion of the chain as changing the item, aka if `controller.source` changes, then the observer will fire.  You'll need to track your id differently to avoid you're observer from firing.  You can create a different observer that always sets the current `id` on a local property, and then it won't fire the update when the chain is broken.

#### Inside the controller

```
currentArticleId: null,

watchArticle: function(){
  this.set('currentArticleId', this.get('article.id'));
}.observes('article.id')
```

And then you would watch `controller.currentArticleId`

Comment: Thanks @kingpin2k, I get the idea but that bit of code with `observes` is throwing an error in my application (and only then, not when commented out): `Error while loading route: article.index Cannot read property 'count' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined`.I tried with `property` instead, but it didn't seem to get called at all. Will carry on testing. Btw, `function(sender, key, value, rev) { };` is nowhere to be found. Sometimes Ember is just too annoyingly complicated.