# Ember.js observer is triggered on initialisation also

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've some troubles with the observer. I would like to observe some model properties but somehow the observer is triggered on initialisation also. I only want to trigger the function when a user is really changing one of those properties.

The observer looks something like this:

```
  watchProperties: function(){
    console.log('Changed :D');
  }.observes('model.propertyOne', 'model.propertyTwo', 'model.propertyThree')
```

The modelhook is set in another route with modelFor and the model is serialised embedded JSON data. Is it possible that one of these things causes the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_addObserver). If you wish to trigger the function only when a property really changes, then you have two options:

- Keeping track of the previous value using `beforeObserver` ([How can an observer find out the before and after values of the observed property in Ember.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234781/how-can-an-observer-find-out-the-before-and-after-values-of-the-observed-propert/9237488#9237488))
- Using `ember-computed-change-gate` (https://github.com/GavinJoyce/ember-computed-change-gate). This isn't ideal either cause you would need to create a duplicate of each property using the changeGate function (see second code example)

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Indeed both options aren't ideal. I think in my case it's easier to observe when the inputs of the properties change. But still, there should be a specific Ember function to deal with this.

Comment: I agree ;) By the way, you might even be able to get away with `model.changedAttributes()` to check which properties are changed & not yet persisted

Comment: Hmm I found another way to only observe changes after initialization. I used the addObserver method to set the observer in the next runloop.  `init: function(){
    this._super();
    var self = this;

    Ember.run.later(function(){
      self.addObserver('model.propertyOne', self.watchProperties);
      self.addObserver('model.propertyOne', self.watchProperties);
      self.addObserver('model.propertyOne', self.watchProperties);
    });

  },  

  watchProperties: function(){
    this.set('propertiesDidChange', true);
  },`